# Vue Cli 3. Geolocation. I cannot update user's location in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-maps, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am using google map api, geolocation.

I want to update user's location, when user logs in or signs up.
But in my firebase database, user's location is null and I can not see a marker at all.

Here is my code. I changed getCurrentPosition to watchPosition once, but it did not work. And in my console, nothing shows up.

My firebase is the latest version. If you need some more codes to answer, please ask me.

When I log in, my place is correctly set, and my location is put center.

```
<template>
    <div class="map">

        <div class="google-map" id="map"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'
import db from '@/firebase/init'

export default {
    name: 'GMap',
    data() {
        return {
            lat: 53,
            lng: -2
        }
    },
    methods: {
        renderMap() {
            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: this.lat , lng: this.lng },
                zoom: 6,
                maxZoom: 15,
                minZoom: 3,
                streetViewControl: false
            })
        db.collection('users').get().then(users => {
            users.docs.forEach(doc => {
                let data = doc.data()
                if(data.geolocation) {
                    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: {
                            lat: data.geolocation.lat,
                            lng: data.geolocation.lng
                        },
                        map
                    })
                    //add click event to marker
                    marker.addListener('click', () => {
                        //console.log(doc.id)
                        this.$router.push({ name: 'ViewProfile', params: { id: doc.id }} )
                    })
                }
            })
        })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    //get current user
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser


        //get user geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {//pos=position
                this.lat = pos.coords.latitude
                this.lng = pos.coords.longitude

                //find user record and then update geocoords
                db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', 'cred.user.uid').get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).update({
                            geolocation: {
                                lat: pos.coords.latitude,
                                lng: pos.coords.longitude,

                            }
                        })
                    })
                }).then(() => {
                    this.renderMap()
                })

            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err)
                this.renderMap()
            }, { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 60000, timerout: 3000 })

        } else {
            //position centre by default values
            this.renderMap()
        }


    }
}
</script>

<style lang="">
    .google-map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
</style>
```

public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB9n8HHOm0YVLwSf6tbuU3p69t8bqlUVSE"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>geo-ninjas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but geo-ninjas doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: console.log(err) is not an apropriate permission denied, position unavailable, timeout or unknow handle - and my guess is you initialize them as null in firestore and they never update due to navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition throwing

Comment: Hello, I changed value from null to another in firebase, but it still doesn't work. Thank you for your advise. If you or someone have other solutions, please let me know,,

Comment: i am not sure if you understood what i ment. your firestore will be updated only when your programm has access to `navigator.geolocation` - and `if(navigator.geolocation)` is most likly the same as `if(true)` but doesnt grant permission